# JQ merging arrays using expression and not slurp

Tags: jq

I have this data:

```json
[
  "USER",
  "TTY",
  "FROM",
  "LOGIN@",
  "IDLE",
  "JCPU",
  "PCPU",
  "WHAT"
]
[
  "lava1",
  "pts/0",
  "157.48.149.102",
  "05:03",
  "31.00s",
  "0.31s",
  "0.31s",
  "-bash"
]
[
  "azureuse",
  "pts/1",
  "157.48.149.102",
  "07:26",
  "0.00s",
  "0.07s",
  "0.05s",
  "w"
]
```

But what I want is:

```json
[
  [
    "USER",
    "TTY",
    "FROM",
    "LOGIN@",
    "IDLE",
    "JCPU",
    "PCPU",
    "WHAT"
  ],
  [
    "lava1",
    "pts/0",
    "157.48.149.102",
    "05:03",
    "31.00s",
    "0.31s",
    "0.31s",
    "-bash"
  ],
  [
    "azureuse",
    "pts/1",
    "157.48.149.102",
    "07:26",
    "0.00s",
    "0.07s",
    "0.05s",
    "w"
  ]
]
```

As the current result of a jq expression I am working on. If I

```bash
echo '[
  "USER",
  "TTY",
  "FROM",
  "LOGIN@",
  "IDLE",
  "JCPU",
  "PCPU",
  "WHAT"
]
[
  "lava1",
  "pts/0",
  "157.48.149.102",
  "05:03",
  "31.00s",
  "0.31s",
  "0.31s",
  "-bash"
]
[
  "azureuse",
  "pts/1",
  "157.48.149.102",
  "07:26",
  "0.00s",
  "0.07s",
  "0.05s",
  "w"
]
' | jq . | jq -s .
```

I get what I want. But, I don't want to have to resort to handing it off to another jq process; it's just not efficient and seems, well, wrong!

I have tried `add` and various forms of `map` and it either gets worse or back to where I started.

**The question:** How can I merge these array in a jq expression instead of passing it to another jq process and slurping it?

Comment: Wrap `$my_expression` into brackets, so its results can be collected into an array.

Comment: nope. That gives the same issue, just with another array around it:

`
[
  [
    "USER",
    "TTY",
    "FROM",
    "LOGIN@",
    "IDLE",
    "JCPU",
    "PCPU",
    "WHAT"
  ]
]
`

Comment: Then your original input is already a stream (hard to say without revealing `$my_expression`). But in that case, move `-s` to the first invocation of `jq` and adapt `$my_expression` accordingly (or otherwise deal with it, e.g. using `-n` and some form of `reduce inputs as …`). Again, hard to tell without `$my_expression` revealed.

Comment: Please show your input file ([mre]) and `$my_expression`. Otherwise, it is impossible to answer

Comment: mmm, sure. You can just use echo, but I will

Comment: I updated the question. The input is part of an unrelated question and I don't want to muddy the discussion with that

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno As said already, either move `-s` to the first invocation of `jq` (`echo … | jq -s '.'`), or use `-n` in combination with `inputs` (`echo … | jq -n '[inputs]'`).

Comment: `jq .` by itself, pretty-printing aside, is a no-op. As a filter, `.` simply takes its input and produces its output.

Comment: @pmf If you turn your comment into an answer I can give credit. I thought I could get the answer I need without giving all the input details, but you did answer the question as asked (and it's something I have been wanting to know anyways)

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno This question, imo, is too general for any conclusive answer. Instead, I'd suggest you write up what you've learned from the various comments as an answer yourself (and accept it if you like). That way, future readers may benefit from following your perspective on narrowing down and resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
jq -s .
```

or

```bash
jq '[ inputs ]'
```

---

> *I don't want to have to resort to handing it off to another jq process*

Simply remove the useless `jq .`.

If `jq .` is really `jq '...'`, then you want

```bash
jq -s 'map( ... )'
```

or

```bash
jq '[ inputs | ... ]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
echo '
["USER","TTY","FROM","LOGIN@","IDLE","JCPU","PCPU","WHAT"]
["lava1","pts/0","157.48.149.102","05:03","31.00s","0.31s","0.31s","-bash"]
["azureuse","pts/1","157.48.149.102","07:26","0.00s","0.07s","0.05s","w"]
' | jq -s
```

another use case:

```bash
echo '["USER","TTY","FROM","LOGIN@","IDLE","JCPU","PCPU","WHAT"]' > A.json
echo '["lava1","pts/0","157.48.149.102","05:03","31.00s","0.31s","0.31s","-bash"]' > B.json
echo '["azureuse","pts/1","157.48.149.102","07:26","0.00s","0.07s","0.05s","w"]' > C.json

jq -s '.' *.json
```